# Getting first row based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe where I want to get the first row where the `indicator` column is 0. For example, my dataframe will look like this:

```
network   volume  indicator  Hour
YYY       20      1          10
YYY       30      0          9
YYY       40      0          8
YYY       80      1          7

TTT       50      0          10
TTT       40      1          8
TTT       10      0          4
TTT       10      1          2
```

The result should look like this:

```
network   volume  indicator  Hour
YYY       20      1          10
YYY       30      0          9
YYY       80      1          7

TTT       50      0          10
TTT       40      1          8
TTT       10      1          2
```

So the ones with ones would still stay, while I get the first time the indicator was 0 for each network. I want to have everything sorted by hour in descending order when I do this, so I get the most recent 0 indicator. How do I go about achieving this result?

Comment: have you tried a simple loop with variable storing the state (whether the last seen value is 0 or 1)?

Comment: What if there is multiple 1 for same network?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala If there is multiple 1 for the same network, then it should still stay there. So we will have all the 1's but the first 0's. I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your required code, with comments inline to help you understand too: (updated the output with your latest dataset, with multiple 1's in the indicator column)

```
sourceData.show()

+-------+------+---------+----+
|network|volume|indicator|Hour|
+-------+------+---------+----+
|    YYY|    20|        1|  10|
|    YYY|    30|        0|   9|
|    YYY|    40|        0|   8|
|    YYY|    80|        1|   7|
|    TTT|    50|        0|  10|
|    TTT|    40|        1|   8|
|    TTT|    10|        0|   4|
|    TTT|    10|        1|   2|
+-------+------+---------+----+


sourceData.printSchema()

root
  |-- network: string (nullable = true)
  |-- volume: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- indicator: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- Hour: integer (nullable = true)
```

Required Transformation Code:

```
//splitting your data set into two parts with indicator 1 and 0
val indicator1Df = sourceData.filter("indicator == 1")
val indicator0Df = sourceData.filter("indicator == 0")

//getting the first row for all indicator=0
indicator0Df.createOrReplaceTempView("indicator0")
val firstIndicator0df = spark.sql("select network, volume, indicator, hour from (select i0.network,i0.volume,i0.indicator,i0.hour,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by i0.network order by i0.Hour desc) as rnk from indicator0 i0) i where rnk = 1")

//merging both the dataframes back to for your required output result
val finalDf = indicator1Df.union(firstIndicator0df).orderBy($"network".desc,$"Hour".desc)

finalDf.show()
```

Final Output:

```
+-------+------+---------+----+
|network|volume|indicator|Hour|
+-------+------+---------+----+
|    YYY|    20|        1|  10|
|    YYY|    30|        0|   9|
|    YYY|    80|        1|   7|
|    TTT|    50|        0|  10|
|    TTT|    40|        1|   8|
|    TTT|    10|        1|   2|
+-------+------+---------+----+
```

Comment: Is there a way to do your answer without spark sql as well, like using the Spark orm?

Comment: You mean to say using Spark Scala DataFrame functions?

Comment: val firstIndicator0df = Window.partitionBy($"network").orderBy($"hour".desc)
    val first0ind = indicator0
      .select($"network", $"volume", $"indicator", $"hour", row_number().over(window).as("rnk"))
      .where($"rnk" === 1)
      .select($"network", $"volume", $"indicator", $"hour")